# iOS, Objective C auto image processing filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm doing a photo app and sometimes the lighting is off in certain areas and the picture isn't clear. I was wondering if there was a feature that can auto adjust the brightness, contrast, exposure, saturation of a picture like in photoshop.

I don't want to manually adjust images like the sample code given by apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html

I want something that will auto adjust or correct the photo

Comment: Did you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_autoadjustment/ci_autoadjustmentSAVE.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone has created it on Github: https://github.com/proth/UIImage-PRAutoAdjust

Once imported, I used it the following:

self.imageView.image = [self.imageView.image autoAdjustImage];

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use AVFoundation to make your implementation of the camera and set the ImageQuality to high and the autofocus or tap to focus feature. Otherwise, I am almost certain you cannot set this properties, The UIImagePicker controller included in the SDK is really expensive memory wise and gives you an image instead of raw data (another benefit of using AVFoundation). This is a good tutorial for this in case you would like to check it out:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297